# What's the fastest way to evaluate a custom function over a range of integers?

Tags: python, runtime

**What is my problem?**

In my project, the end-user is providing me with the set of custom functions with one integer parameter written in Python.

I can enforce on user to use decorators.

The functions can call themselves and each other, for example:

```py
QUX = 100
QUUX = 250

def foo(x):
    if x == 0:
        return QUX
    return foo(x - 1) - bar(x)

def bar(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return QUUX - baz(x)

def baz(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return foo(x - 1) * 0.01
```

The job of the program - that I'm supposed to write - is to:

- calculate the results of the functions (foo(), far(), baz()) on range 0 to 1000
- repeat the calculation with slightly changed constants (QUX, QUUX) many, many times (say 200_000).

So the job of the program is to provide the user with the output of that sort:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

for _ in range(200_000):
    QUX = random.randint(100, 500)
    QUUX = random.randint(150, 750)

    result = pd.DataFrame({
        "foo": [foo(x) for x in range(1_000)],
        "bar": [bar(x) for x in range(1_000)],
        "baz": [baz(x) for x in range(1_000)]
    })
```

**My question:**

What is the fastest way to evaluate these custom functions?

**What did I try?**

1. Caching

I can enforce on user to use a decorator so I can use caching.

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def foo(x):
   ...

@lru_cache()
def bar(x):
   ...

@lru_cache()
def baz(x):
   ...


for _ in range(200_000):
    ...

    foo.cache_clear()
    bar.cache_clear()
    baz.cache_clear()
```

This one is a must. (~45 seconds on 10_000 iterations (instead of 200_000 iterations))

2. Map

Using `map()` inside of list comprehension:

```py
    result = pd.DataFrame({
        "foo": [*map(foo, range(1_000))],
        "bar": [*map(bar, range(1_000))],
        "baz": [*map(baz, range(1_000))],
    })
```

Minor runtime improvement. (~42 seconds)

3. Numpy vectorize

Vectorizing with `np.vectorize()`:

```py
r = np.arange(1000)

vec_foo = np.vectorize(foo)
vec_bar = np.vectorize(bar)
vec_baz = np.vectorize(baz)

for _ in range(10_000):
    QUX = random.randint(100, 500)
    QUUX = random.randint(150, 750)

    result = pd.DataFrame({
        "foo": vec_foo(r),
        "bar": vec_bar(r),
        "baz": vec_baz(r),
    })
```

Minor improvement (~41 seconds)

4. Pybind11 (C++)

I've tried to write the code in C++ and expose it using Pybind11

cpp

```
array<double, 1000> calculate_cpp(function<double(int)> func) {
    array<double, 1000> result;
    for (int t=0; t<1000; t++) {
        result[t] = func(t);
    }
    return result;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(cmake_example, m) {
    m.def("calculate_cpp", &calculate_cpp);
}
```

python

```py
for _ in range(10_000):
    QUX = random.randint(100, 500)
    QUUX = random.randint(150, 750)

    result = pd.DataFrame({
        "foo": calculate_cpp(foo),
        "bar": calculate_cpp(bar),
        "baz": calculate_cpp(baz)
    })
```

No improvement at all.

I still want to try out cython and numba, but given very poor effect of Pybind11 (C++), I'm losing the hope of any solution that would bring me at least a little bit closer to C/C++ speed.

**What do I expect?**

I expect that given that the problem is fairly specified (function always with integer parameter, always applied over a range) an approach exist that is much closer to C/++ speed than Python's speed.

Comment: numba may help.

Comment: You main issue here is recursion, each function call other ones in a circular fashion, this is what takes most time. I'm not sure whether you can combine that and numba, it looks like [caching on recursive functions is currently not supported](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4062)

Comment: For each iteration in the 10k, are you concatenating the result or overwriting the result?

Comment: @JonSG, I will be either summing or concatenating, but that's not relevant for the question asked... or is it?

Comment: I believe it is. If I take your code with just the cache decorator and each outer iteration I append the results of the inner as a tuple, the whole thing runs in 8 seconds on my crappy laptop.

Comment: You have to pay attention to redefine the function for each step of the loop, or to include the constants as parameters. Else, you will run the same functions over and over with the initial constants ([example](https://tio.run/##TYwxCsMwDAB3vUKjPbbZCoa@oHO2EhyZGGLJKDI0@bzrqfS2u@HqaZvw1HtSKZgaRxPZD8ylihru2t5xiRsBzBjwBvD8JVeWz5EvCi9h8rBSwuT8A3CgZE0ZZ6ia2dzofhzC/c97/wI))

Comment: @mozway, oh... I see... I'll edit the snippet and I'll add `.cache_clear()`, thanks.

Comment: `@lru_cache()` has a default size of 128.  Given that you are iterating over 1000 distinct values, you may want to be specific on the size (or just let is grow as large as needed with `@lru_cache(None)`).  Your example functions only go back by one but actual user functions may not be so kind.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate what you are getting with the exception that I will work with lists of lists of tuples as the accumulator rather than concatenating DataFrames as my intuition tells me that might be a pinch point.

Here is what I tried:

```py
import functools
import random
import time

start = time.time()
results = []
for _ in range(10_000):
    QUX = random.randint(100, 500)
    QUUX = random.randint(150, 750)

    @functools.cache
    def foo(x):
        return QUX if x == 0 else foo(x - 1) - bar(x)

    @functools.cache
    def bar(x):
        return 0 if x == 0 else QUUX - baz(x)

    @functools.cache
    def baz(x):
        return 0 if x == 0 else foo(x - 1) * 0.01

    results.append([(foo(x), bar(x), baz(x)) for x in range(1_000)])

print(f"{round(time.time() - start, 4)}s for {len(results)} iterations")
```

That gives me results like:

```
8.7771s for 10000 iterations
```

and if you are seeing results in the 40s range for 10k iteration, then this might be a path forward.

Comment: Looks like pandas dataframe initialization is indeed time-consuming, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to save the results of previous (QUX,QUUX) combinations (in a dictionary for example). With the numbers in your example, there will be roughly 136K distinct pairs out of the 200K samples. Reusing the result (whole dictionary of lists) of already seen pairs should save 30% of the execution time.

for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

seen = dict()
for _ in range(200_000):
    QUX = random.randint(100, 500)
    QUUX = random.randint(150, 750)

    if (QUX,QUUX) in seen:
        data = seen[QUX,QUUX]
    else:
        data = { "foo": [foo(x) for x in range(1_000)],
                 "bar": [bar(x) for x in range(1_000)],
                 "baz": [baz(x) for x in range(1_000)]
                }
        seen[QUX,QUUX] = data
    result = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: If you pass those parameters to the functions and use a cache this should do the same seamlessly ;)

Comment: @mozway, true but only if you cache everything (with distinct entries for QUX,QUUX values) and don't clear caches between runs.  Also, reusing whole lists, and thus not going through the comprehension/function calls, should make this a bit faster as well.